# Unable to create cloud scheduler job for GCP using terraform - VPC Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to create a cloud scheduler job using terraform. The definition is like this:

```
resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job" {
  project          = var.project
  region           = "europe-west2"
  name             = "job"
  description      = "job"
  schedule         = "0 1 * * *"
  time_zone        = "Europe/London"
  attempt_deadline = "60s"

  retry_config {
    retry_count = 1
  }

  http_target {
    http_method = "GET"
    uri         = "https://myprpject/test"
  }
}
```

However, I got an error

```
16:08:23  + /opt/terraform_1.0.5/terraform apply tfplan
16:08:26  module.cloud-scheduler.google_cloud_scheduler_job.job: Creating...
16:08:26  
16:08:26  Error: Error creating Job: googleapi: Error 403: Target type not permitted due to VPC Service Control restrictions.
16:08:26  Details:
16:08:26  [
16:08:26    {
16:08:26      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
16:08:26      "domain": "cloudscheduler.googleapis.com",
16:08:26      "reason": "TARGET_TYPE_NOT_PERMITTED_FOR_VPC"
16:08:26    }
```

I might be related to VPC policy that prevents accessing our company's service using a public IP.

Can someone let me know where I shall look into? I have no clue about this error.